# How do I specify a test config for an ember addon

Tags: ember-cli

My tests depend on a external server. For that I have a configuration like this one:

```
//tests/dummy/config/environment.js
  ENV[] = {
    apiHost: '...'
  }
```

My tests fail because of failed promises, the server is not receiving the requests.

What could cause this? How can I verify that the configuration is being loaded? Or how can I force the file into `ember test`?

Comment: The problem seems to be with nested ember addons that are linked through npm.

Comment: ember cli does not support that